# Is there any performance loss when repeatedly calling UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drawrect

I'm building a `UIView` with a custom `drawRect` function. This is a fairly complex view, with a number of different items that need to be drawn. I've basically broken it down into one function per item that needs to be drawn.

What I'm wondering is should I pass my `CGContextRef`, obtained from `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`, as a parameter to each function, or can I just call it at the start of each function? The latter option looks neater to me, but I am wondering if there is much of a performance penalty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same, unless you are saving/restoring context all around. In any way, getting the context from that method will, most probably, never be the bottleneck.

I suggest that if you are not saving and restoring states, you could use the `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`. However, if you are indeed saving state, you should pass this one since it would be easier to read your code.

It's a matter of style I guess...

Answer (score 3):

Pier-Olivier's response is good, and just grazes the key issue: **don't worry about it until you have to**. This is a case of premature optimization. Before spending a lot of time deciding whether to pass around your `CGContextRef`, you should write your application and then look at the performance. Using [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) can help you figure out where your real bottlenecks are. If it turns out this is causing problems (which I highly doubt), then you can optimize it.

Comment: Fair enough, but what makes you assume I'm not worrying about it because I have to? Having some knowledge of how to avoid certain bottlenecks in the first place rather than spending time identifying them in Instruments is a better way to go, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

just profile after it's implemented correctly and well tested.

if it really shows up as a hotspot, then your problem is likely best divided, and/or rendered to an offscreen context... or by using lower level rendering.